# Range bound indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

## Context

For around 12 days, `$SPX` has been range bound:

[image]

The range is a little over 100.

## Code

I have a simple indicator which aims to show when the price has moved within a range of 100.

```
//@version=5

indicator("My script", "", true)

val = close[0]

n = ta.barssince(math.abs(val - close[1]) > 50)

if n > 1
    label.new(bar_index, hl2[1], str.tostring(n), color = color(na), textcolor = color.orange)
```

The logic here should be:

```
Search backwards until we find a bar with a `close` such that:

    abs(close - current_close) < 50
```

It seems to kind of work for the range shown above:

[image]

## Issue

However, there seems to be an issue. If we zoom out, the indicator labels don't show up anywhere else on the chart:

[image]

There should be many other places on the chart where it shows up.

## Question

What's a good way to set this indicator up so that the other places in the chart that are rangebound are shown?

## Update

Here's another version which uses `while` instead of `barssince`. However, it appears to have similar results.

```
//@version=5

indicator("Range Bound - while", "", true)

n = 1

while math.abs(close - close[n]) < 50
    n := n + 1

if n > 1
    label.new(bar_index, hl2[1], str.tostring(n), color = color(na), textcolor = color.orange)
```

## Update - max_labels_count

Thank you to Bjorn for [his answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72556707/268581).

He mentions:

> By default, there are only about 50 drawing objects (lines, labels) allowed on a chart.

With that in mind, I used `n > 50` to only draw labels if `n` is sufficiently large. This led to more labels showing up.

```
if n > 50
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(n), color = color(na), textcolor = color.orange)
```

He also mentions `max_labels_count`.

Here's another version which appears to work better:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Range Bound - while", "", true, max_labels_count=500)

n = 1

while true

    if n > 1000
        n := 0
        break

    if (math.abs(close - close[n]) > 55)
        break
        
    n := n + 1

if n > 50
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(n), color = color(na), textcolor = color.orange)
```

Here we can see many more labels showing up:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, there are only about 50 drawing objects (lines, labels) allowed on a chart.
Any number greater than that will automatically be cleaned up by the garbage collector process.
See [garbage collection](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings) explained in the usrman.

[A while ago](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/drawings-count-new-parameters-21535/), the user has been given control over the amount of lines or label objects on a chart (with a maximum of 500) through extra parameters in the [study()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study) function: `max_lines_count` and `max_labels_count`.

```
indicator("My Script", overlay=true, max_labels_count=100)
```

This new limit is also explained in the [garbage collection](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings) topic.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Bjorn! Consider adding a bitcoin address to your profile so I can buy you lunch. :-)

Comment: Looks like `study` was the function in V4. It's now `indicator`:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_indicator

Comment: I updated the post with a version which incorporates changes suggested by your answer.